# Is there any way to make 'think-cell' from excel in Apache Echarts?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, echarts

Something like this
[image]

I need to compare any bars with same visual. I can find only this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-stack), but it's only about min-max values and poor visual

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for that. You can make use of the [markPoint](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markPoint) to manually configure any symbol as SVG path together with [markLine](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markLine) for some decent depictions. See this [issue](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19485) for some example code.